# Order data before selecting an option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a dropdown with options that you can order the data by in HTML:

```
<select ng-model="sortOrder" ng-options="option.value as option.name for item in options"></select>
```

Further I have the code that populates the data with ng-repeat and uses sortOrder model to sort the data by dropdown options:

```
<div ng-repeat="hello in worlds" | filter:searchQuery | orderBy: sortOrder"
```

It all works fine and the data gets sorted by the options in the dropdown but I would like to order the data in an alphabetical order before you click on an option in dropdown list. Or maybe an option can be selected by default and sorts the data. 
I've been searching for the answer here on stackoverflow but haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Set default value of `sortOrder` in controller? Note: always use objects in ng-model

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that following are the values in the `sortOrder` model:

```
$scope.options = [
    {
        name: 'Name'
        value: 'name'
    },
    {
        name: 'Address'
        value: 'address'
    }
];
```

where `name` and `address` are properties of your `worlds` model.

This takes care of the `sortBy` - You also would need to `sortIn` feature - ascending or descending. You use another model for that:

```
$scope.sortAscending = false;
```

Thus, your select dropdown will be:

```
<select ng-model="sortOrder" ng-options="item.value as item.name
    for item in options"></select>
```

and your repeated elements will be:

```
<div ng-repeat="hello in worlds" | filter:searchQuery | 
    orderBy:sortOrder:sortAscending"></div>
```

Now, in order to have a default `sortBy`, you need to use the same reference - that way AngularJS will pick the value and bind it correctly

$scope.sortOrder = $scope.options[0].value;

This will set the default sort order to be by the `name` property.